CXF roadmap not clear, blocking us with adoption of Jetty 12
I have an issue with CXF (currently 4.0.4) not supporting Jetty 12 and thus blocking us to use it together with Spring Boot 3.2.0+.
I tried to find what is the roadmap for their development, but it looks pretty outdated.
https://cxf.apache.org/roadmap.html
My problem originates from org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty. Does anybody know more about how and when CXF plan to upgrade to Jetty 12?

It appears to be underway, but not yet released.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-8671
https://github.com/apache/cxf/tree/CXF-8671
https://github.com/apache/cxf/pull/1633


Thanks for feedback, I am aware of those, but they look like nothing is really going on with them. That is why I would be interested in roadmap for release, to be able to plan and asses risk on our site.
